# Programming a 7-segment display interface connected to the parallel port

Tags: python-3.x, wing-ide

I am currently taking the 11th grade computer tech course at my school. We were to program a code so that the interface can output what number or letter I press on the keyboard with pressing the Enter button. Also, when I release my finger off the keyboard, the number or letter on the 7-segment display disappears. I think my code is correct, but the number does not appear on the 7-segment display at all. Due to the length of the code, I am going to only include what should happen if I press the number '1' on the keyboard.

```
import ctypes
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

def Out(addr, byte):
    ctypes.windll.inpout32.Out32(addr, byte)

Out(0x378, 0)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == [K_1]:
            Out(0x378, 6)
```

I appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Does that code actually reproduce the problem? Seems unlikely.

Comment: I think I found the problem. When I rearrange the Out(0x378, 6) to the line above the 'if event.type == [K_1]:' loop, the 7-segment display does light up with the number '1'. So, I'm pretty sure that the problem lies within the 'if event.type == [K_1]:' loop. The problem now that I can't figure out how to make the code so that when i press '1' on the keyboard, the 7-segment display lights up, and when I release the number '1', the 7-segment display turns off.